# Add custom location in hadoop classpath

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera

I am using Cloudera hadoop 5.3.3.

Here is my hadoop class path command output.

```
bash> hadoop classpath
/etc/hadoop/conf:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//*:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/./:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/.//*:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//*:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/./:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/.//*
```

Thought my hadoop psudo node cluster working fine, the following prints nothing.

```
bash> echo $HADOOP_CLASSPATH
```

I want to add a custom location in hadoop classpath. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/to/custom/location:$HADOOP_CLASSPATH;

Even HADOOP_CLASSPATH echo nothing at start but it works for me and the custom class path is actually added to hadoop class path.